# can i retrieve visitor's facebook friends when he likes my site?

Tags: php, facebook-like

i have been googling since morning for an answer that meets what i need but with no luck.

i included a facebook like button to a website i am working on, but i was wondering that after a user presses the button,signs in and like the site, is there a way i can use to retrieve a list of this user's friends on facebook? and post something on their walls instantly? not just post the like on his wall.

Or if that wasn't possible, can i retrieve his friends into a csv file or something so i can later send them emails for example ? ..

what i have in mind is like how certain applications ask us for permission to access personal data in facebook and use them in thing releted to them. well same point ! so can this be done ? and if yes, how ?? 
if you find any links related to this or have previous experience in this domain please post an answer :)
for programming solutions, i use php, yet i am still a junior developer :).
thanx in advance

Comment: I really hope there isn't!  You want to spam all their friends.

Comment: If you could do this, it would be a security breach. I'm pretty sure it's against privacy settings. If you want to integrate with facebook, they have a dedicated page for developers on the site. Good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't get the information you want with a simple Like button.

You would have to create an App, ask for permissions and get the user to agree.

Here is the list of [permissions you can ask](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) for.

To build your App, start [here](http://developers.facebook.com/).

Comment: thank you all , actually JoRouss understood my question the most. i dont want to spam his friends, i want him to grant me permissions to access his friends if he agrees. and not necessarily a like button, anything that that could do the job , i mean his signing in so that i can contact his friends.. applications created in facebook like certain games,post on my wall like : X is sending u a request to play Game Y. how did this happen? my friend X was asked by this application to grant them permission to post on my wall and he agreed.So can an application from outside facebook do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't possible.

Bob liking you does not give you permission to spam all of Bob's friends.